# Java: single-threaded sub-Executor within another multi-threaded Executor

Tags: java, multithreading

I'd like to run some tasks in a serialized way. The typical solution for this is to create an

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor();
```

and run tasks on this one.

However, I already have a thread pool that's multi-threaded.

Is there a simple way of deriving a sub-executor that behaves like a single-threaded one (as in: runs only one task at a time) but is using another (possibly non-single-threaded) executor as a "backend" instead of creating a brand new OS thread?

There are several use cases for why we would want to do this:

- the app might already have a thread pool for e.g. background tasks, with 
  a set priority etc, that we'd like to reuse.
- similarly, we might pass in an Executor that is not just a plain thread  pool (e.g. deferring execution for later, measuring execution time etc.)

  - a subset of which is passing in MoreExecutors.directExecutor() for testing (so that e.g. Futures resolve immediately).

**EDIT**: added the above examples

Comment: Can you put some task code which you want to run in single Thread? I think running a task in single thread would be decided by task itself. If you are not trying to do anything within the task in another thread it will run in the same thread only.

Comment: I agree with Vijendra - your question is interesting, but in order to give more helpful feedback, a bit of code might help us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a zero-threaded executor is called `SerialExecutor` and is described in the java documentation to `java.util.concurrent.Executor`. It has a little drawback, however: for each submitted `Runnable` it creates a wrapper object. [My own implementation](https://github.com/rfqu/CodeSamples/blob/master/src/simpleactor/SerialExecutor.java) does not create additional objects.

Comment: cool, thanks! It's somewhat surprising though that they'd put a useful class in the java _docs_ instead of, well, actual code... I wonder how many times it was copied from there.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: don't go there.

That just doesn't make too much sense from a practical standpoint: you are willing to introduce a more complicated solution for a problem ... that isn't really a problem.

You see: when that "other" multi-thread service idles ... why do have that in the first place? If you want to save on OS threads; why are you using that multi-thread service that seems to be bored to lack of work?

But If it is not idle'ing - how do you think you can "phase in" tasks from that "single-thread" service? In a consistent manner?

And yes, threads aren't exactly cheap; but when you are really at a point where saving that single thread resolves a problem for you ... go back one paragraph and ask yourself again: what about that idle'ing multi-threaded service?

So, maybe there is a technical way to implement your idea; but seriously; my answer is - stick with what you already got:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor();
```

And adding on the other answer/comment: yes the actor model could help here; but mixing up concepts is rarely a good idea. If the Actor approach fits nicely into your overall model (maybe there are good ways to change more parts of your code to make use of that) - fine. But if not; be careful about adding that extra piece of conceptual complexity just to solve a problem ... which as said; might not be a real problem in the first place.

Comment: What topic starter wants is actually an `Actor` which accepts messages of type `Runnable` and processes them by calling to `message.run()`. The concept of Actor is not such complicated, is intuitive enough and is being successfully developed during last 40 years. See details at https://github.com/rfqu/CodeSamples/tree/master/src/simpleactor

Comment: I like your brief answer; thus upvoted; but after thinking some time, I decided to keep my answer around too. Everything depends on "how much of a problem" the OP really has. We don't do things because we can, but because they make sense and improve something that is worth improving. And a solution that works today with two pools; what do you gain by a major rework to use one pool instead? (maybe a lot, but that really really depends on what exactly he is doing; and on which scale that happens).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I do agree that for most of the cases it might be a good idea & OS threads aren't that expensive, after all. However, there might be more weird cases when it could be useful; see the examples I added above.