# Java: Executor Service with multiple queues

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

**Requirement:**

1. I have messages grouped into different types e.g `Type1, Type2 ... Type100`.
2. I want to execute different types of messages in parallel. Let's say in 10 threads, but all the messages of a same type must execute one by one. Execution order does not matter.
3. Once a thread finish all the messages of `TypeX`. It should start processing another Type.

I went through the different answers:
Most of them suggests executor service to handle multi-threading.
Let's say we create executor service like

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

but once we submit the message using `executorService.submit(runnableMessage);`

We don't get any control over the assignment of specific Type of message to a particular thread only.

**Solution:**

creating an array of single threaded executors

```
ExecutorService[] pools = new ExecutorService[10];
```

and initially pass the messages of Type1, Type2 ... Type10
then if any executor has finished execution then assign Type11 to it and keep doing it until all Types gets processed.

**Is there any better way to do it?**

Something like **executor service with multiple queues** where I can push messages of each type to a different queue?

Comment: Well, ExecutorService also offers the ScheduledExecutorService where you can choose between scheduleAtFixedRate() or scheduleAtFixedDelay(). I'd suggest you push your messages into 10 different ArrayDeques, each for the specific message type, which you operate in Queue-Mode (FIFO). Each ScheduledExecutorService operates it's own message queue with the given intervall or delay until you stop the system. This should solve your problem, I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: single-threaded sub-Executor within another multi-threaded Executor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284210/java-single-threaded-sub-executor-within-another-multi-threaded-executor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler solution could be:

Instead of making each message runnable. 
We can create group messages according to their type:

e.g. we create **Group1** for all the messages of **type1**

```
class MessageGroup implements Runnable {
    String type;
    String List<Message> messageList;

    @Override
    public void run() {
      for(Message message : MessageList) {
         message.process();
      }
    }
}
```

And we can create usual executor service with fixed threads like

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

And instead of submitting individual messages we can submit the group of messages like

```
executorService.submit(runnableGroup);
```

and each group will execute the messages of same type sequentially in the same thread.

Comment: This requires you to build the entire list of messages for a group up front, in memory.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend taking a look at [Akka](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/untyped-actors.html).  They provide an Actor framework which would be better suited for this use case.  Short of defining your own implementation of the ExecutorService interface, the default implementations provided by the JDK just do not give one that much control over the scheduling.

Creating a hard coded array of ExecutionServices would not be very dynamic or robust especially as there would be one thread pool per ExecutionService.  One could replace the array with a hash map and then place that behind a custom implementation of the ExecutionService, which would have the advantage of hiding these details from the caller but it would not address the thread wastage of having so many thread pools.

In Akka, each Actor has its own message queue associated with it.  Each Actor effectively runs in its own thread, processing each message one at a time from its queue.  Akka will manage the sharing of threads across multiple Actors.  So if you were to create one Actor per message type, and then you queued the messages with those Actors then you would get the target of having each message type being processed by a max of one thread at a time while being backed by only one pool of threads.

Demo of the technique:

Maven dependency upon Akka.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Java 8 code.  Copy and paste into a Java file and then run the main method within your IDE.

```
package com.softwaremosaic.demos.akka;

import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Function;


public class ActorDemo {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException {
        // The following partitioner will spread the requests over
        // multiple actors, which I chose to demonstrate the technique.
        // You will need to change it to one that better maps the the
        // jobs to your use case.   Remember that jobs that get mapped
        // to the same key, will get executed in serial (probably
        // but not necessarily) by the same thread.
        ExecutorService exectorService = new ActorExecutionService( job -> job.hashCode()+"" );

        for ( int i=0; i<100; i++ ) {
            int id = i;
            exectorService.submit( () -> System.out.println("JOB " + id) );
        }

        exectorService.shutdown();
        exectorService.awaitTermination( 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES );

        System.out.println( "DONE" );
    }

}


class ActorExecutionService extends AbstractExecutorService {

    private final ActorSystem                              actorSystem;
    private final Function<Runnable, String>               partitioner;
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String,ActorRef>       actors = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public ActorExecutionService( Function<Runnable,String> partitioner ) {
        this.actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("demo");
        this.partitioner = partitioner;
    }


    public void execute( Runnable command ) {
        String partitionKey = partitioner.apply( command );

        ActorRef actorRef = actors.computeIfAbsent( partitionKey, this::createNewActor );

        actorRef.tell( command, actorRef );
    }

    private ActorRef createNewActor( String partitionKey ) {
        return actorSystem.actorOf( Props.create(ExecutionServiceActor.class), partitionKey );
    }


    public void shutdown() {
        actorSystem.terminate();
    }

    public List<Runnable> shutdownNow() {
        actorSystem.terminate();

        try {
            awaitTermination( 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES );
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    public boolean isShutdown() {
        return actorSystem.isTerminated();
    }

    public boolean isTerminated() {
        return actorSystem.isTerminated();
    }

    public boolean awaitTermination( long timeout, TimeUnit unit ) throws InterruptedException {
        actorSystem.awaitTermination();

        return actorSystem.isTerminated();
    }
}

 class ExecutionServiceActor extends UntypedActor {
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if (message instanceof Runnable) {
            ((Runnable) message).run();
        } else {
            unhandled(message);
        }
    }
}
```

NB The code above will print 1-100 in an undefined order.  Due to batching (which Akka does to gain extra performance benefits) the order will look mostly serial.  However you will see some randomness to the numbers as different threads intersperse the work.  The longer each job takes to run, the more threads assigned to the Akka thread pool, the more partition keys used and the more underlying CPU cores, the more random the sequence is likely to become.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my very basic example of how it could look like.
You create a Map that contains 10 ArrayDeques addressed by their "Typ". 
Also you start 10 ScheduledExecutors.
Each waits initially 5 seconds and then polls every 200ms its Queue.
In this current example the output will alway be "current message queue of TypeX: null" as the queues are all empty.

But you could now get it on and pass your messages into the matching queues. The service will go and get it every 200ms and do what ever you want with it.
And as you are using queues there is also automatically an order in how the messages are processed.

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Messages {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, ArrayDeque<String>> messages = new HashMap<String, ArrayDeque<String>>();
        ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        long initialDelay = 5000;
        long period = 200;

        // create 10 Queues, indexed by the type
        // create 10 executor-services, focused on their message queue
        for(int i=1; i<11; i++) {
            String type = "Type" + i;

            Runnable task = () -> System.out.println(
                     "current message of " + type + ": " + messages.get(type).poll()
            );

            messages.put(type, new ArrayDeque<String>());
            service.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay, period, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How is It creating 10 executors? and What is the significance of using scheduling messages at fixed rate when I want to execute them for their entire lifecycle?

Comment: The creation happens within the loop. "service.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay, period, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);" The schedule...-method is called 10 times. With each call it creates a new task. These tasks run periodically until cancelled and check every 200 ms the content of their queue. If a new message is present it will be handled. (You have to replace my print-method in the runnable with your particular message-handling-code). So they DO handle your messages for their entire lifecycle. Whenever you put a message in the queues they will be handled as long as the app runs.

Comment: Maybe you intended to design or run you app in an other way. But my code mirrors what I understood in first place. -- You get messages which you divide in particular types. This is covered by my queueing concept. You want to forward those messages and this knowing of which type each message is. Even this is covered using queues and additionally by the 10 scheduled services of which each cares only for his particular queue and runs until cancelled by you.

Comment: In case of further questions, feel free to ask. 

Comment: scheduleAtFixedRate doesn't do what you think it does.  Your solution does not run anything in parallel.  See the javadoc for newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor "Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any given time."  That said, simply change it to newScheduledThreadPool(10)

Answer (score 1):

## Keep one executor service per message type

Yes, the array of executor services you mentioned at the end of your Question is the right idea.

But let’s make it a `Map` to be more mangeable.

```
Map < MessageType , ExecutorService >
```

Let’s define an enum for your message types.

```
enum MessageType { Type01, Type02, Type03 }
```

And the map.

```
Map < MessageType , ExecutorService > messageTypeExecutorMap =  new EnumMap<>( MessageType.class ) ;
```

Populate the map with an executor service per message type. You want each message type collection processed one by one, so use a single-threaded executor service.

```
for( MessageType messageType : MessageType.values )
{
    messageTypeExecutorMap.put( messageType , Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() ) ;
}
```

To submit a message for processing, retrieve an executor service by message type.

```
messageTypeExecutorMap
.get( task.getMessageType() )
.submit( task ) ;
```

There is nothing wrong with keeping a surplus of executor services up and ready for work. If they are not executing tasks, they take little overhead in terms of either memory or CPU. Just be sure to have enough cores on your deployment machine to support the highest number of message types you expect to be executing simultaneously.